How to Decrypt and Save the Files from a Phone
I accidentally wiped the metadata partition along with Dalvik/ART Cache and Cache using TWRP and now I can't boot into the OS. Internal Storage and USB-OTG were excluded.
I know that the data is still on the phone, but that it's encrypted, so I've already tried the following:

Inside TWRP > Wipe > Advanced Wipe, I tried to Repair or Change File System, but no luck there.

I connected the phone to a PC and used these adb commands to try to backup the raw data:



adb pull /dev/block/by-name/userdata
adb pull /dev/block/by-name/metadata

This backed up everything (128 GB of userdata - the whole phone memory, and the metadata partition which is 16 MB), so If I'm correct, this should be my data, but it's encrypted. Since the metadata partition was wiped, I now have no access to the keys that are used to decrypt this data.
My question is, how can I decrypt this or mount it somewhere, either on the phone or Windows/Linux? What do I do next with the files that I backup up?

I have also tried to flash a newer version of the ROM using fastboot, so that the phone will hopefully boot, but that didn't help either. Probably because the Internal Storage says 0mb, I got lots of errors while trying to flash it with fastboot.

Is there any way to backup my data (files, photos...)? Either by somehow fixing what I did wrong and booting into the OS or just by connecting the phone to a PC and using adb or any other method?
When I boot into TWRP, the Internal Storage says 0mb and the TWRP built-in File Manager can see some folders and files but cannot access all of them. For example, it doesn't show anything inside the data folder, which is what I care about saving.
But inside TWRP > Mount, there's an option that says Decrypt Data. When I click on it, it asks for a password. What is this password, and where is it stored?
It’s not the PIN used to unlock the phone, so what is it?
If there’s no way to find out the current password, how can I find it when the phone is fully working and decrypted, so I have it in case I need it later?
The phone is Poco F3 with Android 13 Custom ROM from Xiaomi.eu, rooted with Magisk v27 and alioth TWRP version 3.7.0-12-POCOF3-v7.9_A13, if that helps.
I know I can flash a new ROM and boot the phone. But right now, I don't care about fixing the phone, just about my data, and I just want to save it if possible in any way? It may even be encrypted, doesn't matter, as long as I can decrypt it later and access it.

Please do not crate a new, very close question to your last post. Instead edit your last post and add new information if you want to extend it.
